# FOR UPDATE with IN clause causes LOCK WAIT TIMEOUT

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, mariadb

I am facing the LOCK WAIT TIMEOUT issues when using the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` statement.

I have prepared the scenario which I do not understand. Could you tell me why the first three blocks are executed immediately, but the last one waits?

Thanks.

```
-- I'm using MariaDb

-- T1 is the mysql terminal window 1
-- T2 is the mysql terminal window 2

CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
) COMMENT='' ENGINE='InnoDB' COLLATE 'utf8_bin';

INSERT INTO test SET name='foo';

T2: START TRANSACTION;
T1: START TRANSACTION;
T1: SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN (1) FOR UPDATE;
T2: INSERT INTO test SET name='foo'; -- executed immediately

T2: START TRANSACTION;
T1: START TRANSACTION;
T1: SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN (1,2) FOR UPDATE;
T2: INSERT INTO test SET name='foo'; -- executed immediately

T2: START TRANSACTION;
T1: START TRANSACTION;
T1: SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN (1,2,3) FOR UPDATE;
T2: INSERT INTO test SET name='foo'; -- executed immediately

T2: START TRANSACTION;
T1: START TRANSACTION;
T1: SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4) FOR UPDATE;
T2: INSERT INTO test SET name='foo'; -- waits for T1 to commit

T2: commit;
T1: commit;
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the transaction mechanisms of innodb, but ransactions normally begin with "start transaction" do a bunch of SQL statements and then "commit". However, your code does not follow this simple pattern. Why "start transaction" two times?

Comment: And what is the meaning of "T1" and "T2"? sessions??

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but beginning a transaction should cause any pending transaction to be committed by the implicit commit. So I didn't write any commits to make the example as minimalistic as possible. T1 is one mysql terminal window, T2 is the terminal window two. Forogt to mention it, will update the original question, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about the "implict commit", but "start transaction" is also needed for the "select .. for update".

Comment: The other strange thing about your code is the sequence of operations. Although you put select before the insert, in fact the insert must execute first because it has the first "Start transaction"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InnoDB row-level locks are [index-locks in reality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-record-level-locks.html). A less documented feature<sup>*</sup> is: if the locking `SELECT` does not (or cannot) use a (user-defined) index, then only the default clustered index can be used, and the entire table becomes locked.

It is very likely that the optimizer decided that the index is not useful to check the "long" list of `IN()` parameters (probably because most of the table needs to be scanned). This whould lead to the unexpected side-effect you detected.

This hypothesis can be confirmed by checking the [execution plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html).

Comment: * I am still unable to find a reference for this, but all my tests concur. I'd be pleased to see an official source.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RandomSeed, that is exaclty what happen, confirmed by the EXPLAIN statement. When I add the FORCE INDEX statement then the example works as expected. Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are assuming that "select for update" only locks the rows for UPDATE. However, the locking also applies to INSERT, because an insert can insert a record that falls under the original "select". The documentation states that it "locks the rows and any associated index entries".

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: I think that this is not the problem you mentioned because the id column is the AI primary key so it locks just the rows I need. There are no FK in the example table and it works for first three blocks but fails later. If this was the problem you mentioned then it should fail constantly all the time I hope.

Comment: Yes but the primary key has an index which should be locked (or at least for the affected entries).